# Can I POST values into MySQL and view it on Bootstrap Modal at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form and it posts values into MySQL database however I want to show the values in the modal once I submitted the form but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my **form** snippet:

```
 <form action="menuactions/temporesto.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label class="control-label">First Name:</label>
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="John" type="text" name="first_name" required autofocus/>
<br />
<label>Last Name:</label>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Doe" type="text" name="last_name" required/>
<br />
<label>Contact:</label>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Email/Phone Number" type="text" name="contact" required/>
<br /><label>Order Date:</label>
<input class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yy" type="text" name="eventdate" required/>
<br />
    <label>Event Time:</label>
    <br />
    <select id="eventtime" class="form-control" name="eventtime1">
     <option value="item0">--Select Time--</option>
     <option value="11:00 am - 2:00 pm">11:00 am - 2:00 pm</option>
     <option value="6:00 pm - 9:00 pm">6:00 pm - 9:00 pm</option>
     <option value="7:00 pm - 10:00 pm">7:00 pm - 10:00 pm</option>
     <option value="3:00 pm - 6:00 pm">3:00 pm - 6:00 pm</option>
     <option value="4:00 pm - 7:00 pm">4:00 pm - 7:00 pm</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <label>Event Hours:</label>
    <br />
    <input class="form-control" id="eventhours" value="3 Hours" type="text" name="eventhours1" readonly/>
    <br />

 <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#checking">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

And this is my **modal**:

```
 <!-- Modal -->
 <div id="checking" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; </button>
     <h4 class="modal-title">Reservation Information</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
       <label><h2>Name: <?php echo $row['first_name'];?> </h2></label>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Or do I have to open it up on a new page instead of a Modal?

I can submit the values into MySQL fine but it won't show up on the modal.

Answer (score 3):

If the end goal is to make the modal content dynamic you have two choices:

1. Use two modals, one for the form submission, which you then close on submit, and then open the 2nd modal. Perhaps by reading the response from the first submission which contains all of the content you need to populate the 2nd modal. This means that the user sees the 1st modal hide and the 2nd show, which might not be ideal.
2. Use 1 modal but make the actual body content dynamic. You will most likely need to do this client-side in some fashion. E.g. the first run through the modal knows its in **submit** mode so presents that UI, then upon submission which gets the new content (or maybe you have to make a new server endpoint which just returns the new content) the modal switches to **display** mode where you then update the DOM elements inside the modal. Depending on how much content you have you might need to have the modal re-trigger its height checking and adjust itself.

For #2 either way we're assuming you have some kinda of a response payload which tells you what the new modal content should be, this might be in JSON, raw text, XML, etc. This payload might be the response from the first form submit or it might be from hitting another server endpoint after the submit which returns a representation of the new content.

In terms of implementing #2 you can do it by use straight Javascript/jQuery, and create new DOM elements on the fly or you can use a client-side templating language (like Handlebars or Mustache) or maybe you implement a solution like Vue.js which just manages that modal content.

Ultimately, my guess is that its going to be client-side manipulation but where you go from there depends on your data and how much of a complex UI you need to build in the 2nd modal.